# I want my images to be responsive in bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Someone told me that you can have responsive images in bootstrap via inbuilt css. Kindly help me out.Right now i use this custom css

```
page-header .logo img {
   position: absolute;
   top: 240%;
   left: 126%;
   width: 200px;
   height: 150px;
   padding:1px;
   border:1px solid #021a40;
   background-color:#000;
   margin-top: -250px; /* Half the height */
   margin-left: -250px; /* Half the width */
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use class img-responsive.
For detailed info go to [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#images)
e.g: 
`<img src="..." class="img-responsive" alt="responsive image">`

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Bootstrap, it comes with a class that is used to handle responsive images called [`img-responsive`](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#images-responsive). Simply add it to your `<img>` and it should work as expected :

```
<img src="..." class="img-responsive" alt="Now I am responsive">
```

It should be noted that depending on how your `<img>` is positioned (e.g. absolutely, relative, fixed, etc.) and sized can affect how responsive it will be. By adding it alone to your current class, it won't really be noticable, however if you change your class as follows :

```
page-header .logo img {
   position: absolute;
   padding:1px;
   border:1px solid #021a40;
   background-color:#000;
}
```

and use the following markup :

```
<page-header>
    <div class='logo'>
        <img src='http://www.trythisforexample.com/images/example_logo.png' class='img-responsive' />
    </div>
</page-header>
```

It should work as expected as [seen in this example](http://jsbin.com/xepedub/edit?html,css,output) :

[image]